# Member 'changeAccountConfirmDialog' expects argument of type 'Author'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, associated-types

```
internal enum PlayBroadcasterDialogLiveType: Equatable {
    case error
    case exit
    case liveOnOtherDevice
    case stopped
    case paused
    case freezed
    case reconnected
    case disconnected
    case liveIsModerate
    case changeAccountConfirmDialog(Author)


    internal var shouldExitToLiveReport: Bool {
        return self != .liveOnOtherDevice && self != .disconnected && self != .error 
&& !isLiveModerate && self != .freezed && self != .changeAccountConfirmDialog
    }
}
```

In case of argument in changeAccountConfirmDialog, how shall I implement the functionality for this variable.

the error I am getting is "Member 'changeAccountConfirmDialog' expects argument of type 'Author'"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if case...` for the enum case with an associated value.

```
internal var shouldExitToLiveReport: Bool {
    if case .changeAccountConfirmDialog = self {
        return false
    }
    return self != .liveOnOtherDevice && self != .disconnected && self != .error 
        && !isLiveModerate && self != .freezed
}
```